# Tesseract setVariable white or blacklists without effect in genesis tesseract 4 using c#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, whitelist, genesis

I'm trying to set white and blacklists for my ocr-tool. This is importend for me to optimize the results.

Using white or blacklists has no effect. I read that this issue is fixed in Tesseract 4.1 but it`s not working. The variable is going to be set but without any effect of the result.

Let us say the real image text is "AB123CD". By setting the whitelist to "123" my expactation is, that tesseract only recognizes these characters. My expected result text is "123". In fact it`s still "AB123CD".

```
private TesseractEngine tesseract = new TesseractEngine(path, "eng", EngineMode.LstmOnly);

tesseract.SetVariable("tessedit_char_blacklist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
tesseract.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "123");
using (var page = tesseract.Process(image, rec, PageSegMode.Auto))
{
    text = page.GetText(); // text contains still letters.
    using (var iterator = page.GetIterator())
    {
        iterator.Begin();
        do
        {
             string symbol = iterator.GetText(PageIteratorLevel.Symbol);
        } while (iterator.Next(PageIteratorLevel.Symbol));
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The preferred terms these days are ‘blocklists’ and ‘allowlists’

Comment: @stuartd Of course you are right. I use Tesseract as a wrapper and I don't think I have any influence on the naming.

Comment: Same issue here, did you solved?

Comment: @ErniBrown Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it just doesn't make sense to set both a White list and a Black list.

Try to only set only of them, not both. For me it works fine. I'm using current last version of Tesseract for C# (5.2.14). NuGet package TesseractOCR

Comment: I am currently implementing a new version with the package TesseractOCR. I would like to know how do you set one of them. Maybe you can give me a little example. Afterwards I can tell you if it`s running correctly. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I'm using same SetVariable as in the initial post. Usually no real need of the BlackList, WhiteList is much enough for my needs. For instance to filter on digits, or dates. 

Also I have very bad results when only looking for a single character recognition. And setting SingleCharacter mode doesn't help. 
In other situations, I'm pretty satisfied by the results I get from TesseractOCR.

Thank you for your good work. It's really great to have a free version that easy to use.